# Mapping "long" to create an object

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

iam trying to map just a long field coming from my url route to create a Query Object from my controller, can i use auto mapper

CreateMap(MemberList.None);

Source :-long id

Destination:-

```
public class GetPlanQuery : IRequest<PlanDto>
    {
        public long Id { get; }
        public GetPlanQuery(long id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        internal sealed class GetPlanQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetPlanQuery, PlanDto>
        {
           //Logic will go here
        }
    }
```

Map i am using is as below

```
CreateMap<long, GetPlanQuery>(MemberList.None);
```

i am getting an exception while executing as

```
System.ArgumentException:
needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args.'
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lucian correctly suggested you can achieve this kind of custom mapping by implementing [ITypeConverter](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html):

```cs
public class LongToGetPlanQueryTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<long, GetPlanQuery>
{
    public GetPlanQuery Convert(long source, GetPlanQuery destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new GetPlanQuery(source);
    }
}
```

then specify it's usage in AutoMapper configuration:

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<long, GetPlanQuery>()
    .ConvertUsing<LongToGetPlanQueryTypeConverter>();
```

#### EDIT

Alternatively, you can just use a `Func`:

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<long, GetPlanQuery>()
    .ConvertUsing(id => new GetPlanQuery(id));
```

Comment: For such a simple converter a Func overload works better.